# How to load local images with webview on Android 11.0？

Tags: android, webview, richtext

How to use the WebView to load the local storage pictures on Android 11.0？

There is a richtext :

```
<img src="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20210604_110651.jpg" alt="dachshund" width="100%"><br><br>
```

/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20210604_110651.jpg is a local image.

This is part code of how to load the image:

```
String data = "<img src=\"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20210604_110651.jpg\" alt=\"dachshund\" width=\"100%\"><br><br>";
binding.webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, data, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

My code could work Under android 10 and 10，but not work in Android 11.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

These permissions have been obtained.

Any help Thanks in advance.

Comment: `There is a richtext :` Rich text? I see no rich text. And a WebView uses html source. Can you load a rich text document in a WebView? That is new for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of the problem was eventually discovered.
This is because the webSetting.setAllowFileAccess method defaults to true in 29 and earlier versions, and false in 30 and later versions.

```
 /**
 * Enables or disables file access within WebView.
 * Note that this enables or disables file system access only. Assets and resources
 * are still accessible using file:///android_asset and file:///android_res.
 * <p class="note">
 * <b>Note:</b> Apps should not open {@code file://} URLs from any external source in
 * WebView, don't enable this if your app accepts arbitrary URLs from external sources.
 * It's recommended to always use
 * <a href="{@docRoot}reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader">
 * androidx.webkit.WebViewAssetLoader</a> to access files including assets and resources over
 * {@code http(s)://} schemes, instead of {@code file://} URLs. To prevent possible security
 * issues targeting {@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#Q} and earlier, you should explicitly
 * set this value to {@code false}.
 * <p>
 * The default value is {@code true} for apps targeting
 * {@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#Q} and below, and {@code false} when targeting
 * {@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#R} and above.
 */
public abstract void setAllowFileAccess(boolean allow);
```

So add follow code solve this problem：

```
binding.webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

of cause let targetSdkVersion <=29 will also okey.

Comment: Superb, thank you!