# loadDataWithBaseURL not working correct with targetSdkVersion>=30

Tags: android, sdk

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///" + imagePath(), htmlWithImage, "text/html", "utf-8", "");

not displaying images in the HTML page, which are stored in imagePath(), when setting targetSdkVersion to 30 or more.

With targetSdkVersion=29 there is no problem showing the images.

I need to update targetSdkVersion to 30, otherwise I can't publish the app. Google Play Console says I need to update to 30.

Any hints?

Comment: Following solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67999281/how-to-load-local-images-with-webview-on-android-11-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worked for me:

```
String base64version = Base64.encodeToString(htmlData.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
webView.loadData(base64version, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "base64");
```

And if not working just add this line:

`webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);`

Because the webSetting.setAllowFileAccess method defaults to true in 29 and earlier versions, and false in 30 and later versions.

Comment: I figured out myself. You are right with the setAllowFileAccess. Is there a way to give the bounty insteed it is expired?

Comment: @mcflysoft Thanks, I am not actually is there a way to give bounty.